# How to change css positions, widths, durations, and delays dynamic?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am using CSS3 to control my transitions and I've made my #wrapper's width 100%. However, when I animate divs across the entire width, it doesn't work right.
1. The animated birds duplicates if the browser's width is max out.
2. The animated birds will not move across the screen if the browser's width is resized to a much smaller size.
3. The clouds and the birds also resets or flicker every so often.

The [demo page is here](http://lorcho.stoutwebtech.com/UnitedWeStand/). I was wondering by setting these values to dynamic it might resolve the issue mentioned above. However, I'm not sure how to set these values dynamically based on the size of the browser's window. If I set the #wraper's to a fixed width and all the transitions and animations to a fix width it works fine.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Can you provide some practical code? It'll be better if you share a jsFiddle link with your code.

Comment: Here's the jsFiddle link.

http://jsfiddle.net/2Charlie/yF8Lf/1/

Comment: You may need to use media queries to give CSS values based on your viewport size.. or else you can go for some responsive frameworks..

Comment: Thanks! I'm familiar with media queries but can you point me to explanations about responsive frameworks?